# is it possible to return database data like withinput and use it with {{old()}} laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have articles database table and need same form for both saving new article and updating old one. So I have made a forms folder and created my form, then I included it in both places i needed, but in article edit I need to see all article which i am editing info (title, article content, etc.) and that info is saved in database. It would be the best if i could use {{old()}} and see article info from database (because when i save article, if there are any errors, i want not to loose all post inputs data, so i use {{old()}} there) Sorry, my english is not really good and it's really hard for me to formulate... So my questions sounds: Is it possible to return database data from controller like withInput() and use it with {{old()}}? Thank you! Ask if i said something not understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, the function old() accepts a second parameter, a value if the old value is not defined. In this case, you use the value of the database

Example

```
{{ old('username', $user->username) }}
```

Comment: Thanks! i will think about how to use it in my situation :)

Comment: i use it like this value="@if(isset($article_info)){{old('article_title',$article_info->article_title)}}@else{{ old('article_title')}}@endif" now, is it okay?

Comment: if you want to use  the same form to create and update would be an option

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer below should work, I believe that the best way to solve it is binding the model on your form (use the Form::model, instead of the Form:open).

This way, when you use old('some_field'), it will get the some_field field that the Model refers to.

You can have more information here: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#form-model-binding